# Should I use "it" or "them" or some other pronoun when I say "I need to sweep **them/it** into a dustpan and dump **them/it** to the garbage"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

This is a sub-quesiton from this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/237367/108307).

If I am supposed to merge these two, please leave a comment rather than giving a down voting.

suppose this scenario, there are 9 coffee beans on the floor, I treat them as rubbish.

[image]

question_1
Should I use "it" or "them" or some other pronoun when I say "I need to sweep **them/it** into a dustpan and dump **them/it** to the garbage".

I guess both works, and I need a double confirmation.

question_2
should I treat "the beans" as countable or uncountable when I treat them as rubbish?

I guess it is uncountable, and again, I need a double confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the pronoun is referring to.

If you said *the beans* that's countable, and you'd refer to them in the plural:

> "I've dropped **the beans** on the floor and now I need to sweep **them** up."

If you called it *a mess*, you'd refer to that in the singular:

> "I've dropped the beans on the floor and made **a mess**! I need to sweep **it** up."

Similarly, if you referred to it as *rubbish* that would be uncountable and take a singular pronoun.

> "There is **rubbish** on the floor and I need to sweep **it** up."