# What should I say when I see mess on the floor? what blah blah blah all this stuff on the floor?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

there are a few coffee beans on the floor, such a mess.

[image]

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/OyIytwRIKTM?t=16) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> what blah blah blah all this stuff on the floor?

to describe such a mess, what the blah is in what she is saying here?

Comment: "Oh, no! What did I ...? What is all this stuff on the floor?"

Comment: @user105719 Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? 
I'll accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy to provide the comments that I make because I've come to realize how hard it is to learn this perverse language. And you're kind to offer me rep points. Thank you in return. But it requires more effort to construct a good answer than I'm willing to spend. Plus I'm not sure how much authority I can offer beyond "that's what I hear, and I've been good at it for a long time since I'm a native speaker."

Comment: Please be aware that you're trying to learn vernacular English from videos that mimic conversational English. They're not real conversations, of course, since only one party is involved. You're getting all the hesitations, backtracking, and other tics of unrehearsed spoken language without the benefit of actual back-and-forth speech.